# Convexity of p power of the q norm (0<p<1, q>1)

Tags: convex-optimization, convexity

I encountered a minimization problem involving the following function:

$f(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{x}\|_q^p$

Here, $q>1$ and $0<p<1$. Naturally, each entry of $\mathbf{x}$ is greater than $0$.

I would like to determine the convexity (or concavity) of $f$, but I'm uncertain about how to do it. In my previous experience, I could demonstrate convexity by checking the definition or using rules of convexity, such as the convexity of the sum of two functions or certain composition rules. Or, I could prove the positive semi-definiteness of the Hessian. However, I haven't been able to apply any of these techniques to analyze $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $q > 1, 0 <p < 1$, as per the question:

If $x$ is a nonnegative scalar, $f(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{x}\|_q^p$ is concave, not convex.

For non-scalar $x$, $f(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{x}\|_q^p$ is neither convex nor concave. For instance, for p = 0.5, q = 2, in 2D at $x = [1, 1]^T$, the Hessian of $f(x)$ has eigenvalues of 0.297 and -0.149; so the Hessian is indefinite there, and therefore $f(x)$ is neither convex nor concave.

Comment: What value of $p$ are you using in your example? For $p=1$ (granted just outside the specified scope) and $q=2$, $f$ would be the euclidean 2 norm.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone, would you please, where can we find a material to learn about the norms and their specifications? (I know there are some books, but I appreciate if it has been dense with focus on only norms).

Comment: @ptubin Sorry. I forgot to include the value of p used in my example, which is 0.5.  I just edited my answer to include that. It wasn't hard fr me to find a "counterexample". The set of values in my answer was the first ones I tried. I come up with such counterexamples to convexity or concavity very frequently over at https://ask.cvxr.com/ .

Comment: @A.Omidi Read and solve some exercises in at least the first 4 or 5 chapters of "Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/ to learn something about convex optimization, and determining convexity and concavity. You can pick up something about norms from Appendix A and supplement that with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics) .

Comment: @prubin, with $q = 2$, and $x = [1,1]^T, p = 1-10^{-9}$ is not convex (nor concave). With other values of $x$, perhaps $p = 1 - \epsilon$ is sufficient for non-convexity. Even though q = 2 is not on the edge of convexity for a norm (which is at q = 1), there's no room to spare for allowing $0 < p < 1$

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, thank you so much for your comments. 